# Create a boolean matrix from a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, stringr

I have the following matrix:

```
> myletters <- matrix(letters[1:4], ncol = 2)
> myletters
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "c" 
[2,] "b"  "d"
```

Now I want to check whether there is an "a" or "c" in each cell.

```
> str_detect(myletters, "[ac]")
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Now I have a logical vector but I want to have a matrix.
My desired output would be:

```
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE
```

Don't get me wrong, of course I know some possibilities how to come up with this but I think a solution like `matrix(str_detect(myletters, "[ac]"), ncol = 2)` is quite ugly. There has to be a better way?
And I don't know why this happens. What's the difference between this situation and the following where I get my desired output?

```
> matrix(1:4, ncol = 2) > 2
      [,1] [,2]
[1,] FALSE TRUE
[2,] FALSE TRUE
```

Comment: `myletters == "a" | myletters == "c"` works for the example matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assign it back to get the structure of the original data on the lhs of `<-`.  A `matrix` is a `vector` with `dim` attributes.  When we use `str_detect`, the attributes are lost and thus we get a plain vector.

```
library(stringr)
out <- myletters
out[] <- str_detect(myletters, "[ac]")
class(out) <- "logical"  
out
#     [,1]  [,2]
#[1,]  TRUE  TRUE
#[2,] FALSE FALSE
```

Or another way to do this on the fly is using `structure`

```
structure(str_detect(myletters, "[ac]"), dim = dim(myletters))
#      [,1]  [,2]
#[1,]  TRUE  TRUE
#[2,] FALSE FALSE
```

---

Or use `apply`

```
apply(myletters, 2, str_detect, "[ac]")
#       [,1]  [,2]
#[1,]  TRUE  TRUE
#[2,] FALSE FALSE
```

---

Or if we need `purrr` syntax, convert to `data.frame` and apply `map` over the columns

```
library(purrr)
as.data.frame(myletters) %>%
    map_df(str_detect, "[ac]")
```

When we convert to `data.frame`, the `mutate_all` can also be applied

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(myletters) %>%
      mutate_all(str_detect, "[ac]")
```

Comment: Thank you! I like the `apply`-way. Do you know how I can achieve this with `purrr`-functions? I usually prefer them over `apply` family.

Comment: @TobiSonne  Thee purrr family `map`, loops through columns of a data.frame.  Here it is a `matrix`, so, you may need to convert to `data.frame` or tibble i.e. `as.data.frame(myletters) %>% map_df(str_detect, "[ac]")`

Comment: Oh, of course! My data originally was a `data.frame` so this solution is even better! Thank you for your great answer!

Answer (score 2):

One option is

```
out <- `dim<-`(myletters %in% c("a", "c"), dim(myletters))
out
#      [,1]  [,2]
#[1,]  TRUE  TRUE
#[2,] FALSE FALSE
```

The function `` `dim<-` `` does

> Retrieve or set the dimension of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the solution of `apply` by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59128818/12158757), here is a solution with `base R`, using `apply()` and `grepl()`

```
apply(myletters, 2, function(v) grepl("[ac]",v))
```

which gives

```
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE
```